# R function returns 0, code inside same function when run outside of function returns correct value

Tags: r, dataframe

Okay, so I'm new to stackoverflow and R. This is probably a pretty silly problem, but I couldn't find a solution anywhere.

Packages

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Here is the the code

```
sample_size_finder <-  function(variable, value){
  df %>% 
    select(variable) %>%
    filter(variable == value) %>%
    count()
}
```

- **df = data frame I imported earlier**
- **variable = the name of the column I want to select and filter from**
- **value = the value in that column I want to filter for**

I want the function to look for the column in my data frame specified by the argument **"variable"**, select it, and filter from it all observations that are equal to the argument **value**. Then, count() all those observations.

When I try to run the function

```
sample_size_finder("team_size", 4)
```

it returns

```
  n
1 0
```

Which is zero and therefore the wrong output.

Running the code inside without the function wrapped around it with the same arguments

```
df %>%
    select(team_size) %>%
    filter(team_size == 4) %>%
    count()
```

returns

```
   n
1 12
```

which is the correct output (12 observations for team_size equal to 4).

I narrowed my issue down to the variable argument in my sample_size_finder(variable, value) function. Here is what I tried so far:

- changed the function to only have "value" as an argument. This gives the desired output, but I want to have the "variable" argument included
- changed the function to only have "variable" as an argument. This returned "0" as output
- ran the function without putting "variable" in string quotes. This returned "0" as output

I'm almost ready to give up and just use the code without the function, but somehow this bothers me a lot. It would be so appreciated if a kind soul would help me :)

All the best,
Matthias

Comment: Have you tried debugonce(sample_size_finder) and run your variants, with and without 'variable' (you have to debugonce() on each variant), and stepped through >s # at a step, then ls() and examine interim results per 'step' to assess why you might not need 'variable'? And welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I receive a error message: `Error in debugonce(sample_size_finder("team_size", 4)) : 
  argument must be a function`

Comment: You just put debugonce(the_function_you_are_debugging's_name), then you use your function and you will be in debug mode, that you step through using 's', 'n', or 'c'. 's' is the smallest step. and you ls() along the way to determine whether 'variable' is in fact required...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.data` to access column names as variable name in the function.

```
library(dplyr)

sample_size_finder <-  function(variable, value){
  df %>% 
    select(.data[[variable]]) %>%
    filter(.data[[variable]] == value) %>%
    count()
}

sample_size_finder("team_size", 4)
```

This can be written in base R as -

```
sample_size_finder <-  function(variable, value){
  sum(df[[variable]] == value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use `across` with `all_of`

```
library(dplyr)
sample_size_finder <-  function(variable, value){
  df %>% 
    select(all_of(variable)) %>%
    filter(across(all_of(variable), ~ . == value)) %>%
    count()
}

sample_size_finder("team_size", 4)
```